# Creating a struct

Tags: c, shell, pointers, posix

Mat told me to create a struct

> create a struct for the individual commands and arguments. It should
>   have something like the "executable" name, number of args and arg
>   list. Create a few functions to create such a struct, free it, and add
>   to the argument list

So i did.

```
struct str_list {
    char *const *name;
    int argc;
    char *const *argv;
};
```

Is it ok? The goal is to look like this.

```
int run_cmd(const char *cmd) {
  assert(cmd);
  struct str_list *chunks = str_split(cmd, '|');
  struct pipeline *pipe = alloc_pipeline(chunks->size);
  for (int i=0; i<chunks->size; i++) {
    pipe->command[i] = parse_command(chunks->data[i]);
  }
  int status = execute_pipeline(pipe);
  free_pipeline(pipe);
  free_str_list(chunks);
  return status;
}
```

The code actually looks like this

```
static int runCmd(const char *cmd) {
    int freeme_len = 0;
    char *pString1[z];
    char *pString[z];
    *pString1 = "\0";
    *pString = "\0";
    bool quote = false;
    int argc = 1;
    int n = 0;
    int status = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int i2 = 0;

    struct command shellcommand[BUFFER_SIZE];

    char **ptr1;
    char **argv = alloc_argv(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char **new_argv = alloc_argv(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char ***matrix = alloc_matrix(BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    char ***pString4 = alloc_matrix(BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);

    char *cmdtmp;
    char *pString3[64];
    cmdtmp = strdup(cmd);
    ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
    for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) { /* loop for each pipeline */
        n++;                 /* save number of pipelines */
        char *string1[z];
        int e = 0;
        *pString = "\0";
        *string1 = strdup(ptr1[i]);
        if ((*string1[0] != '\0') &&
            !isspace(*string1[0])) {
            w = parse_command(w, new_argv, string1, pString, &i2, n, quote, i, matrix, pString1,
                              e, &argc, argv, pString4, &freeme_len);;
        }
        free(*string1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        shellcommand[i].argv = matrix[i];
    }
    fflush(NULL);
    /* refactor to a function */
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        return -1;
    }
    /* If we are the child process, then go execute the string.*/
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* spawn(cmd);*/
        fork_pipes(n, shellcommand);
    }
    /*
     * We are the parent process.
     * Wait for the child to complete.
     */
    while (((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) < 0) && (errno == EINTR));
    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error from waitpid: %s", strerror(errno));
        free(cmdtmp);
        if (ptr1) {
            for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
                free(ptr1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(ptr1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "pid %ld: killed by signal %d\n",
                (long) pid, WTERMSIG(status));
        free(cmdtmp);
        if (ptr1) {
            for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
                free(ptr1[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            free(ptr1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    free(cmdtmp);
    if (ptr1) {
        for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) {
            free(ptr1[i]);
        }
        free(ptr1);
    }

    free_matrix(matrix, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    free_matrix(pString4, BUFFER_SIZE, BUFFER_SIZE);
    free_argv(argv, BUFFER_SIZE);
    free_argv(new_argv, BUFFER_SIZE);

    return WEXITSTATUS(status);
}
```

My allocation and deallocation functions look like the following but I didn't do it yet for a `struct only for arrays and matrices but I think that I can have an array of structs with one struct and use these functions for the struct.

```
*/
/* returns an array of arrays of char*, all of which NULL */
char ***alloc_matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    char ***matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(char **));
    if (!matrix) abort();

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = malloc(columns * sizeof(char *));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            matrix[row][column] = NULL;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}

/* returns an array of char*, all of which NULL */
char **alloc_argv(unsigned rows) {
    char **matrix = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
    if (!matrix) abort();

    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        matrix[row] = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
        if (!matrix[row]) abort();

    }
    return matrix;
}

/* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
void free_argv(char **argv, unsigned rows) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {

        free(argv[row]);
    }
    free(argv);
}

/* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
void free_matrix(char ***matrix, unsigned rows, unsigned columns) {
    for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (unsigned column = 0; column < columns; column++) {
            //    printf("column %d row %d\n", column, row);
            free(matrix[row][column]);
        }
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

My forking and exec looks like these

```
/* Helper function that spawns processes */
int spawn_proc(int in, int out, struct command *cmd) {
    pid_t pid;
    fflush(NULL);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        if (in != 0) {
            if (dup2(in, 0) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(in);
        }
        if (out != 1) {
            if (dup2(out, 1) < 0)
                err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdout for %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
            close(out);
        }
        /*fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd->argv[0]);*/
        fprintf(stderr, "[%d]\n", (int) getpid());
        execvp(cmd->argv[0], cmd->argv);
        err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd->argv[0]);
    }
    else if (pid < 0) {
        err_syserr("fork failed: ");
    } else {
        /* printf("** we are the parent ***"); */
    }
    return pid;
}

/* Helper function that forks pipes */
void fork_pipes(int n, struct command *cmd) {
    int i;
    int in = 0;
    int fd[2];

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {

        if (pipe(fd) == -1) {
            err_syserr("Failed creating pipe");
        }

        spawn_proc(in, fd[1], cmd + i);
        close(fd[1]);
        in = fd[0];
    }
    if (dup2(in, 0) < 0) {
        err_syserr("dup2() failed on stdin for %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
    }
    /*fprintf(stderr, "%d: executing %s\n", (int) getpid(), cmd[i].argv[0]);*/
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    execvp(cmd[i].argv[0], cmd[i].argv);
    err_syserr("failed to execute %s: ", cmd[i].argv[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Mixed use of array indexing with `unsigned` and `int`.  `size_t` should be used.
2. Rather than `*pString1 = "\0";`, `*pString1 = "";` is certainly sufficient.
3. Miss-guided comment.  There is no `NULL`-ness in the array - just some uninitialized values in `matrix[row][]`.  Could use `calloc()` instead.

   ```
   /* returns an array of char*, all of which NULL */
   char **alloc_argv(unsigned rows) {
   ```
4. Over-size allocation `matrix[row] = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));`.  `matrix[row]` is an allocation to an array of `char`, not an array of `char *`.
5. Suggested using `sizeof *pointer * N` rather than `N * sizeof type` in `malloc()`.  Less chance to code incorrectly as OP did originally.

   ```
   // matrix[row] = malloc(rows * sizeof(char *));
   matrix[row] = malloc(sizeof *(matrix[row]) * rows);
   ```
6. When de-allocating, especially in debug mode, consider setting the pointer to `NULL`.  This helps detects invalid subsequent usage.

   ```
   /* deallocates an array of arrays of char*, calling free() on each */
   void free_argv(char **argv, unsigned rows) {
     for (unsigned row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
       free(argv[row]);
       argv[row] = NULL; // add
     }
     free(argv);
   }
   ```
7. Declare when code can be given a value: [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

   ```
   // char **ptr1;
   // ... Many lines later
   // ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');

   char **ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
   ```
8. `if (ptr1) {` serves no purpose - it is too late as `ptr1[i]` occurred beforehand.  Maybe add `if (ptr1) {` right after

   ```
   ptr1 = str_split(pString3, cmdtmp, '|');
   for (int i = 0; ptr1[i]; i++) { /* loop for each pipeline */
   ... dozens of lines later
   if (ptr1) {
   ```
9. IMO `free_like()` functions should handle free-ing `NULL` just like `free(NULL)` works.

   ```
   void free_argv(char **argv, unsigned rows) {
     if (argv) {
       ...
     }
   ```

In general, the code functionality was not clear like what is `z` in `char *pString1[z];` and why is `alloc_argv()` allocating `rows*rows`?

Comment: You will get a bounty a.s.a. p. because I like this answer. `z` was my quickfix for a constant that I changed to `BUFFER_SIZE` i e array length. My programming was focused on getting correct output with bad code and then fixing the code because users usually don't care about variable names and usability is king.

Comment: Can `alloc_argv` and `alloc_matrix` be the same since an array is a matrix?

Comment: If I use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, will the code be `  matrix[row] = calloc(columns , sizeof(char *));` ? The matrix code should be able to handle the array data, do you agree?

Comment: @Programmer 400 `matrix[row] = calloc(columns , sizeof(char *));` is a problem as `alloc_argv(unsigned rows)` does not pass in `columns` and `matrix[row]` points to a `char`, not a `char *`.